# 2 pre_get_posts functions to filter by custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

EDIT: See the last (3rd) code snippet, it's the working one.

I have an "Actions" page (an archive for a custom post type called Actions), which is an equivalent to "events".

I used [this tutorial](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/) to filter them with custom fields: ville (city), action (type of action) and date and it works perfectly.

Then I created another function to filter by "date range": past, future actions. And it also works. But they "accumulate". When I select "Past" actions and a city, it shows me ALL past actions + ALL actions that happened or will happen in a city.

So these two functions work, but I don't know how to set their relation to AND or something that makes them work together instead of "accumulating".

Can someone please help me figure this out ?

Thank you.

Function to filter by Type/City/Date custom fields:

```
// array of filters (field key => field name)
$GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array( 
    'action'  => 'action', 
    'ville'   => 'ville', 
    'date'    => 'date',

);

// action
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // bail early if is in admin
    if( is_admin() ) return;

    // bail early if not main query
    // - allows custom code / plugins to continue working
    if( !$query->is_main_query() ) return;

    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    // loop over filters
    foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ) {

        // continue if not found in url
        if( empty($_GET[ $name ]) ) {

            continue;

        }

        // get the value for this filter
        // eg: http://www.website.com/events?city=melbourne,sydney
        $value = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);


        // append meta query
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => $name,
            'value'     => $value,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );

    } 

    $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'date' => 'DESC' ) );

    // update meta query
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    return;

}

?>
```

Function for Future/Past actions:

```
<?php

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'future_past_actions', 10, 1);

function future_past_actions( $query ) {

// bail early if is in admin
    if( is_admin() ) return;

    // bail early if not main query
    // - allows custom code / plugins to continue working
    if( !$query->is_main_query() ) return;

    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');


    if( isset($_GET['range']) ) {

    $range = explode(',', $_GET['range']);

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'range',
        'value'   => $range,
        'compare' => 'IN',
        );


        if( $query->get( 'range' ) == 'future' ) {
             $meta_query[] = array(
             'key' => 'date',
             'value' => date("Ymd"),
             'compare' => '>',
            );
            $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';
        }

        elseif( $query->get( 'range' ) == 'past' ) {
             $meta_query[] = array(
             'key' => 'date',
             'value' => date("Ymd"),
             'compare' => '<',
            );
            $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';
        }

        elseif( $query->get( 'range' ) == 'toutes' ) {
           return;
        }

    }

    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'date' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'date' => 'DESC' ) );
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    return;

    }

    ?>
```

The final merged and working code:

```
 <?php
// array of filters (field key => field name)
        $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array( 
            'action'    => 'action', 
            'ville'     => 'ville', 
            'date'      => 'date'
        );

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // bail early if is in admin
    if( is_admin() ) return;

    // bail early if not main query
    // - allows custom code / plugins to continue working
    if( !$query->is_main_query() ) return;

    if( ! is_post_type_archive( 'actions' ) ) return;

     // CITY/TYPE/DATE filters
    // loop over filters
    foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ) {

        // continue if not found in url
        if( empty($_GET[ $name ]) ) { continue; }

        // get the value for this filter
        // eg: http://www.website.com/events?city=melbourne,sydney
        $value = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);

        // append meta query
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => $name,
            'value'     => $value,
            'compare'   => 'IN',  
        );
    }

        // FUTURE/PAST/ALL filters
    if( isset($_GET['range']) ) {

    $range = $_GET['range'];

      if($range != "toutes") {

          // Select what kind of compare you need
          if($range == "past") {
            $comparer = '<';
          } else if($range == "future") {
            $comparer = '>=';
          }

        // If you need to filter by date add this to meta_query array
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'date',
            'value'   => date("Ymd"),
            'compare' => $comparer,
            );
          }
       }

    // update meta query
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'date' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'date' => 'DESC' ) );
    $query->set('posts_per_page', '20');

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case best solution in my opinion is to have one action and check query arguments inside of it and then decide what kind of logic you want to do.

$query variable has all the arguments you assign, so your code might look something like this:

Editing considering the comments on situation, you have to use AND relation between two meta fields. Code inside action should look like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  $meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'ville',
        'value'   => '$value',
        'compare' => '=',
    )
  );

  // Select what kind of compare you need
  if($range == "past") {
    $compare = ">";
  } else if($range == "future") {
    $compare = "<";
  }
  if($range != "all") {
    // If you need to filter by date add this to meta_query array
    $date_query = array(
        'key'     => 'date',
        'value'   => 'date(\"Ymd\"),',
        'compare' => $compare,
    );
    $meta_query[] = $date_query;
  }
  $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'date' => 'DESC' ) );

  // update meta query
  $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
}
```

Because what you do now, you set query arguments multiple times.
If you need more parameters to filter out you can add them conditionally to $meta_query variable considering what kind of parameters you get.

I think if I understand correctly this kind of meta query should return needed results.

Comment: Well "?range=future" and "?range=past" serve a different purpose than date/city/type filterings. So it wouldn't help to merge them.

I used  ` if( $query->get( 'range' ) == 'future' ) { ` to make the query get future events, so I have to continue and use ` if( $query->get( 'range' ) == 'past' ) { ` to make the query get the past ones, and == 'all' to get all events... it can't be just an if/else statement.

Comment: You want to filter by city and past/future actions?
Something like this: http://www.website.com/events?city=melbourne,sydney?range=future

Comment: City, actions (type), past/future.
Here's the webpage (http://montasserdrissi.com/uecse/actions/) so you have an idea

Comment: Anyways the problem is still that you overwrite your meta_query with later data:
 $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

If you can see this part(second block of code), you can have 2 dimensional array of meta queries:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query

So if you have one pre_get_posts filter, and construct array of meta queries in a way you need to, you will get desired results.

Comment: I will edit solution a little bit later to suit your case better, but issue is that you shouldn't do 2 separate actions, but construct needed meta_query and then set it.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried to merge them (see the third code I put in the post), but now it doesn't filter, the query gets whatever I selected: if I select a city and past events, it'll display all past events (not just from the city) and all events from that city (even if it's a future event) ...

Comment: Edited code example, this kind of query should do the work for described scenario, if you don't have date range, then don't include the date meta_query array

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally works.
I kept the part of my code that deals with filters and used your if/else statement and the variable $compare to deal with the date range :)